how do I correctly disable caps-lock on my keyboard?
There are really two problems. One is that I accidentally hit caps-lock while I am doing some things and it is a hassle. The other is that caps-lock is on when I am trying to log in to my machine. I want for both of these to go away.
I tried a few things. One involved using setxkbmap and the other was another utility which I cannot locate at the moment. Neither worked. gnome-tweaks appreared to work, but now things seem confused.
When I try to log on it says caps-lock is on. Hit the caps-lock and it still says this. Btw, my password uses lower case. But I have to type it, holding down the shifr key, for it it work. And the caps-lock light is now on regardless of whether caps-lock is on or not.
Any suggestions for this hassle?
I am running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and lshw says:
  *-input:6
       product: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
       physical id: 9
       logical name: input2
       logical name: /dev/input/event2
       logical name: input2::capslock
       logical name: input2::numlock
       logical name: input2::scrolllock
       capabilities: i8042

